# SQLite: How to return count of zero from left join?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, left-join

I have two tables: players (id, name) and goals (id, player_id). I want to return a list of all players and the number of goals they have associated with them, even if they have no goals associated with them. I have tried:

```
SELECT player.name AS player_name, 
       COUNT(goal.id) AS goals 
  FROM player 
       LEFT JOIN goal 
       ON player.id = goal.player_id
 GROUP BY player 
 ORDER BY goals DESC;
```

But the problem is that it only returns one player with zero goals, and I can't figure out why. I know it's something to do with the GROUP BY clause. There are definitely many players with zero goals.

Answer (score 3):

You are grouping by the entire table, instead of single field in the player table that is unique (such as `player.name` perhaps).

Comment: It always seems so obvious in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to group by `player.name`. I'm surprised you're not getting an error that `player` is not a defined column.

Comment: Now that you mention it I don't understand why there is no error there. But thanks grouping by player.name fixed it.